# Does the browser start rendering HTML when the first data packet is recieved

Tags: html, performance, browser

In a web browser (mobile if that matters), I assume that when you access a webpage a number of packets of HTML data are returned. If that is correct, do web browsers begin rendering the HTML before all of the HTML packets have been returned?

I ask this because I'm writing a webpage and I've heard that above the fold content should have lower latency than below the fold content and I was wondering why this would matter if the browser waits for the entire HTML response before processing.

Comment: That is entirely up to the authors of the browser. As such, it's a question about the implementation of specific pieces of software and I don't think that's computer science. [webmasters.se] might be more appropriate but please check their help center to see what's actually on-topic there.

Comment: To learn the gory details of how web browsers process the content and prepare for rendering, I'd recommend you read up on the [Critical Rendering Path](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/). One solid option for learning is the [Website Performance Optimization](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud884) course created by Google and Udacity.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, web browsers will generally attempt to render pages based the data they have available if only part of the content is available within a short time period. The rendered page is updated periodically as more content becomes available.

Keep in mind, however, that certain factors may prevent a browser from rendering partial content, especially:

- External `<script>` elements within the body of a document halt rendering until the script can be loaded. (This is because the external script may contain calls to `document.write()`, which could change the interpretation of the document.)
- Some browsers cannot render HTML tables until the entire table is available.
- Browsers will usually attempt to download stylesheets before rendering the page, to avoid a FoUC ("flash of unstyled content"). If the stylesheet doesn't arrive, though, browsers will eventually give up and work with what's available.
- Some web application frameworks and/or programming languages may have features which prevent any content from being sent until it has been fully generated.